# docker suspend and resume using criu

Tags: docker, checkpointing

I am building docker from this version of this source code:

https://github.com/boucher/docker/tree/cr-combined

after cloning the code :

```
git clone -b cr-combined --single-branch https://github.com/boucher/docker.git
```

cd docker

```
#make build
#make binary
```

And then copied the resulting file @./bundles/../docker to the usr/bin directory
After reopening the terminal and starting the docker engine again.
its shows that i am using my own built version but
This version should have two main docker commands that won't show up in my built one
1- checkpoint
2- restore

could you please help me and tell me where it went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/boucher/docker
$ cd docker
$ git checkout cr-combined
$ env AUTO_GOPATH=1 DOCKER_EXPERIMENTAL=1 \
    DOCKER_BUILDTAGS='exclude_graphdriver_btrfs \
    exclude_graphdriver_devicemapper' ./hack/make.sh binary
$ ./bundles/1.10.0-dev/binary/docker-1.10.0-dev  --help | grep checkpoint
checkpoint Checkpoint one or more running containers
restore    Restore one or more checkpointed containers
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: # Try this instead: make all
#

# WARNING! DOCKER_EXPERIMENTAL is set: building experimental features

bundles/1.10.0-dev already exists. Removing.

---> Making bundle: binary (in bundles/1.10.0-dev/binary)
Building: bundles/1.10.0-dev/binary/docker-1.10.0-dev
vendor/src/github.com/boltdb/bolt/bolt_unix_solaris.go:10:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/unix" in any of:
 /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/golang.org/x/sys/unix (from $GOROOT)
 /home/walid/docker/.gopath/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix (from $GOPATH)
 /home/walid/docker/vendor/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix

Comment: and do you need criu to be installed before.

Comment: It now works but i used the make command instead of ./hash/make.sh