# Docker Container Migration with criu

Tags: docker, migration

With Help from Saied Kazemi I was able to checkpoint and migrate a container using criu on ubuntu 14 by this [docker suspend and resume using criu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278619/docker-suspend-and-resume-using-criu/34318665#34318665)

Now I am trying to migrate this container from one location to another.

I am using these steps:

```
export cid=$(docker run -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null)
docker exec $cid touch /test.walid
mkdir /tmp/docker-migration
mkdir /tmp/docker-migration/$cid
docker checkpoint --image-dir=/tmp/docker-migration/$cid $cid
ssh walid@192.168.1.10 mkdir /tmp/docker-migration
ssh walid@192.168.1.10 mkdir /tmp/docker-migration/$cid
scp -r /tmp/docker-migration/$cid walid@192.168.1.10:/tmp/docker-migration
ssh walid@192.168.1.10 mkdir /tmp/$cid 
scp -r /var/lib/docker/0.0/containers/$cid walid@192.168.1.13:/tmp
ssh -t walid@192.168.1.10 sudo mv /tmp/$cid /var/lib/docker/0.0/containers/
ssh -t walid@192.168.1.10  sudo docker restore --force=true --image-dir=/tmp/docker-migration/$cid $cid
```

and Got this response

Error response from daemon: No such container: fea338e81750b2377c2a845e30c49b7055519e39448091715c2c6a7896da3562
Error: failed to restore one or more containers

Both Machines have docker and criu installed and checkpoint works alone.

Answer (score 1):

Docker container migration using CRIU is still under development.  So far the focus of checkpoint and restore integration into Docker has been C/R'ing on the same machine.

That said, it is possible to manually migrate containers by not only copying the container image created by CRIU after checkpoint (as you have done) but **also by copying the container directory** created by Docker in /var/lib/docker/0.0/containers/$cid **as well as the container's root filesystem** in /var/lib/docker/0.0/image.  Manually migrating container's filesystem is a bit tricky specially if you are using a union filesystem like AUFS or OverlayFS.  Also, you need to restart the Docker daemon on the destination machine to see the container.

Answer (score 0):

On the destination machine, you have to create or run a container. This container will be overwritten by the restored image.

So : 
ssh -t walid@192.168.1.10 export NewID=$(docker run -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null)
ssh -t walid@192.168.1.10  sudo docker restore --force=true --image-dir=/tmp/docker-migration/$cid $newID

In my case, that worked like a charm!

Comment: This will make you loose the container ID, Any data you have changed in the file system, and check @Saied Comment

Answer (score 0):

here is my test:

migration container across nodes.

restore:
*vagrant ssh vm2 -- 'docker run --name=foo -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null && docker rm -f foo'*

```
docker create --name=CONTAINNER_NAME base_image

docker restore --force=true --image-dir=/tmp/{dump files}
```

github: https://github.com/hixichen/criu_test

Comment: It's not clear whether you're posting a solution to the OP's problem or you're having a similar problem and posting your code that doesn't work. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry,I should make it clear.I faced the same issue but when I run the 'docker run --name=foo -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null && docker rm -f foo'. I got a correct restore.