# docker restore; lack of indication to go-dockerclient - FIXED

Tags: docker, restore, checkpoint

I followed Saied Kazemi's instructions on [docker suspend and resume using criu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278619/docker-suspend-and-resume-using-criu/34318665) and used https://github.com/boucher/docker/tree/cr-defunct (based on feedback from Ross Boucher) to buid 1.10.0-dev from source to get checkpoint/restore functionality.

I am now trying to work with docker-proxy (github.com/edmodo/docker-proxy) which in-turn relies on go-dockerclient (github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) to get indications on containers being created, etc.

My question is more specific to the underlying triggers that the docker daemon is sending to the go-dockerclient. When containers get created, started or stopped, the appropriate indicators are being received.

However, when I use restore, I am not seeing what I had hoped to see. Perhaps I don't fully comprehend how restore works. I ran the docker daemon in debug mode to see what was happening

I first checkpoint a running container `a1` as

```
docker checkpoint --image-dir=/tmp/ABC --leave_running a1
```

The corresponding debug at the daemon was

```
DEBU[0036] Calling POST /v1.22/containers/a1/checkpoint 
DEBU[0036] POST /v1.22/containers/a1/checkpoint         
DEBU[0036] form data {"ImagesDirectory":"/tmp/ABC","LeaveRunning":true,"WorkDirectory":""} 
DEBU[0036] Using CRIU 20000 at: criu                    
DEBU[0036] Using CRIU with following args: [swrk 3]     
DEBU[0036] Using CRIU in DUMP mode                      
DEBU[0036] CRIU option ImagesDirFd with value 22
<snip> .... I can paste this as well if needed        
DEBU[0036] CRIU option EmptyNs with value 1073741824
```

Then, I create a new container `a2` as

```
docker create --name=a2 alpine-sshd
```

The corresponding debug log for the create at the daemon was:

```
DEBU[0051] Calling POST /v1.22/containers/create        
DEBU[0051] POST /v1.22/containers/create?name=a2        
DEBU[0051] form data:{"AttachStderr":true,"AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":true,"Cmd":null,"Domainname":"","Entrypoint":null,"Env":[],"HostConfig":{"Binds":null,"BlkioDeviceReadBps":null,"BlkioDeviceReadIOps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteBps":null,"BlkioDeviceWriteIOps":null,"BlkioWeight":0,"BlkioWeightDevice":null,"CapAdd":null,"CapDrop":null,"CgroupParent":"","ConsoleSize":[0,0],"ContainerIDFile":"","CpuPeriod":0,"CpuQuota":0,"CpuShares":0,"CpusetCpus":"","CpusetMems":"","Devices":[],"Dns":[],"DnsOptions":[],"DnsSearch":[],"ExtraHosts":null,"GroupAdd":null,"IpcMode":"","Isolation":"","KernelMemory":0,"Links":null,"LogConfig":{"Config":{},"Type":""},"Memory":0,"MemoryReservation":0,"MemorySwap":0,"MemorySwappiness":-1,"NetworkMode":"default","OomKillDisable":false,"OomScoreAdj":0,"PidMode":"","PortBindings":{},"Privileged":false,"PublishAllPorts":false,"ReadonlyRootfs":false,"RestartPolicy":{"MaximumRetryCount":0,"Name":"no"},"SecurityOpt":null,"ShmSize":null,"UTSMode":"","Ulimits":null,"VolumeDriver":"","VolumesFrom":null},"Hostname":"","Image":"alpine-sshd","Labels":{},"OnBuild":null,"OpenStdin":false,"StdinOnce":false,"StopSignal":"SIGTERM","Tty":false,"User":"","Volumes":{},"WorkingDir":""} 
ERRO[0051] Couldn't run auplink before unmount: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH 
DEBU[0051] container mounted via layerStore: /var/lib/docker/0.0/aufs/mnt/a02ad092a4ae9d0ae40f26a8457fe8379e63a8362444aedb6d41c67d34b2cb83 
ERRO[0051] Couldn't run auplink before unmount: exec: "auplink": executable file not found in $PATH
```

At this point of time, the `a2` container is created, but not running. This creation **causes an indication to the dockerclient that a container has been created**, but not running. `docker ps -a` and `docker ps` reveal two (`a1` and `a2`) and one (`a1`) containers respectively; as expected.

After that, I restore `a2` with the checkpointed image using

```
docker restore --force=true --image-dir=/tmp/ABC a2
```

The corresponding debug for restore was:

```
DEBU[0083] Calling POST /v1.22/containers/a2/restore    
DEBU[0083] POST /v1.22/containers/a2/restore?force=1    
DEBU[0083] form data {"ImagesDirectory":"/tmp/ABC","LeaveRunning":false,"WorkDirectory":""} 
DEBU[0083] container mounted via layerStore: /var/lib/docker/0.0/aufs/mnt/a02ad092a4ae9d0ae40f26a8457fe8379e63a8362444aedb6d41c67d34b2cb83 
DEBU[0083] Assigning addresses for endpoint a2's interface on network bridge 
DEBU[0083] RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, <nil>, map[]) 
DEBU[0083] Assigning addresses for endpoint a2's interface on network bridge 
INFO[0083] No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4] 
INFO[0083] IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers : [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844] 
DEBU[0083] Using CRIU 20000 at: criu                    
DEBU[0083] Using CRIU with following args: [swrk 3]     
DEBU[0083] Using CRIU in RESTORE mode                   
DEBU[0083] CRIU option ImagesDirFd with value 29        
<snip>.... I can paste this if needed
DEBU[0083] CRIU option EmptyNs with value 1073741824
```

This starts up the container. However **no kind of indicator is seen via the daemon to the dockerclient**.  Both containers work normally.

Is this lack of indication by design ? Is there some other method in which one could get a trigger of a container having started ? I have to dig deeper into go-dockerclient to see if I am missing something there

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This branch represents the latest working version of docker with checkpoint restore: https://github.com/boucher/docker/tree/cr-defunct

There's also a precompiled version: https://github.com/boucher/docker/releases/tag/v1.10_2-16-16-experimental

I believe that, although the "start" event won't fire, a "restore" event should be fired by the daemon.

Comment: I am going to follow instructions on http://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump related to socat to see if I can look into what exactly is happening on /var/run/docker.sock. Perhaps the problem is in go-dockerclient that it doesn't process all indicators

Comment: OK. Turns out I messed up the updates I had made to docker-proxy to detect these indicators. go-dockerclient is working flawlessly (thanks fsouza !!) and my proper changes to docker-proxy were enough to get the indicators. I am able to get 'checkpoint' and 'restore' events when those actions are taken. I am accepting Ross's answer since he pointed out that that is exactly what would happen and also pointed me to the correct c/r repo and branch